# Symfony2 Query Builder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I am trying to get records from a table where patentgroup_id is null. I tried this

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:SvPatents');
$qb1 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('sv')
    ->select('sv')
    ->where('sv.patentgroup = :patentgroup')
    ->setParameter('patentgroup', null)
    ->getQuery();
    $nogroup_patents = $qb1->getArrayResult();
   var_dump($nogroup_patents);
```

There is one record in the table whose patentgroup_id is null but I am getting empty array.

Any ideas? What I am doing wrong

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same way you would do it in SQL

```
->where('sv.patentgroup IS NULL')
```